# Running a bash shell using a password with a cron job

Tags: bash, mysql, cron

I have a bash shell to back up a database that requires a password to open it. I want to run on a cron job, but how do I make it run automatically without filling in the database password?

ubuntu server version : 20.04.3
Mysql version : 8.0.26

The command i tried : `mysqldump -u root -p "dbname" > backupname.sql`
when I press enter, the system asks for password. when i remove `-p`, error occurs.

Comment: What does the script look like?

Comment: Does [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72417/credentials-file-for-running-mysql-related-jobs-via-script) help?

Comment: If you are using MySQL on a modern version of Ubuntu, and you haven't intentionally overridden the permissions mechanism of the software, then you do not need to supply a password when doing a backup via `mysqldump`. The `root` system account will connect to the `root` MySQL account without a password, as this is part of administration 

Comment: @David I haven't written the command yet because I want to know how to do it first

Comment: @Ray it looks like entering user password, not mysql database password

Comment: @matigo I have tried, but the system asks to enter the mysql database password

Comment: Please [edit] your question to answer these questions: (1) What version of Ubuntu are you running? (2) What version of MySQL are you running? (3) What *exactly* have you tried? (with code samples) — Until these three questions are answered, it will be almost impossible for anyone to offer any sort of solution.

Comment: @matigo I have edited it, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `mysqldump` with the `root` MySQL account, you will need to prefix your command with `sudo`:

```
sudo mysqldump database_name > backup.sql
```

If you would like to run this via a cron job, then you can do something like this:

```
0 3 * * * mysqldump database_name > /path/to/backups/backup.sql
```

As a bonus, if you would like to compress that backup and have the file name contain the date, you can do something like this:

```
0 3 * * * mysqldump database_name | gzip > /path/to/backups/backup_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).gz
```

Be sure to include the necessary `--routines` and `--triggers` options in your `mysqldump` command if your database contains either stored procedures or triggers.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can either add the following to you `my.cnf`file

```
[mysqldump]
user=mysqluser
password=secret
```

Alternatively, you can export the following before calling `mysqldump`

```
MYSQL_PWD=yourverysecretpassword
```

Using the `-p` parameter as you tried is strongly discouraged for security reasons.

More info and extended solutions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293042/how-to-perform-a-mysqldump-without-a-password-prompt